# How can I access Scala implicit functions like toInt() as function objects?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to write a general-purpose String converter function that takes a string and a conversion function and applies the function to the string:

```
def convertString[A](s: String, f: String => A): A = f(s)
```

I'm trying to pass the `toInt` function as `f`, but my IDE keeps complaining that it `Cannot resolve symbol toInt`.

How do I get access to `toInt` as a function object that I can work with like any other function?

Comment: `convertString("4", _.toInt)` is valid code, don't know what you tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(_: String).toInt` works:

```
scala> val myStr = "4"
scala> convertString(myStr, (_: String).toInt)
res0: Int = 4
```

Basically, we need to force Scala to implicitly cast the input String object to a StringOps object, then call toInt on that StringOps object. Unpacking the magic, we can try the following:

```
scala> val f = (_: String).toInt
f: String => Int = <function1>
```

We have to specify that the input type is a String, and then Scala takes care of implicitly casting the String to StringOps when `toInt` is called. This is equivalent to saying

```
scala> def f: String => Int = _.toInt
```

but is more concise.